# Could not read from remote repository with 413 error

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, remote-repository

I tried to add my existing project to gitlab through SSH key but I get this error, one of the solution said that I should maximize the size of NGINX but I follow steps to maximize it but nothing happens. So, is there another solution to fix this error?

**This response:**
[image: this response]

Answer (score 0):

It appears GitLab is rejecting your transfer because the payload is too large. Have you considered sending the files in a compressed format to try to circumvent the 413 error?